# Send js variable to php file on submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to pass a javascript variable that is created by dynamically created textboxes.

The code is at http://pastebin.com/X4tFqHNw because the php would break the code look on here.

As you can see in the code it's passing everything else fine but i can't figure out how to post the tag variable to the php file. Is there a way to pass the tags as seen below to the php?

```
    function save(e) {
    var tags = multiTags.find("input.tag").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');
    alert(tags);
    return false;
}
```

website is here: http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.php. You'll notice that when clicking add it creates a new box (as seen in the js). I'd like those values passed, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look here -> http://forum.jquery.com/topic/passing-value-to-hidden-form-field. I guess it should be enough to get you to a solution.

Comment: In the future, try to add some code so that we have something to reference if that link dies.  :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function save() {
    var tags = new Array();
    $('input.tag').each(function(index){
        tags[index] = $(this).val();
    });
    tags = tags.join(',');
    alert(tags);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery for that
    $('#target').submit(function() {
       $('').val(value);
    });
You could target a hidden input. And then pass that variable as POST data.